# Visual Studio project dependancies

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

.NET 4.0
VB.NET

If I have the following Solution/Projects:

- SolutionA

  - ProjectA
  - ProjectA.Interfaces
  - ProjectA.UnitTests
- SolutionB

  - ProjectA
  - ProjectB

    - Project Dependency on ProjectA
  - ProjectB.Interfaces
  - ProjectB.UnitTests

Should SolutionB also contain ProjectA.Interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any project in SolutionB has a dependency on ProjectA.Interfaces then it should be included.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy. Currently it does not have any reference dependencies on the Interfaces Project, but before SolutionB can build, you have to open SolutionA to generate the ProjectA.Interfaces binary that ProjectA depends on.

Comment: Yeah, if you include it in the solution then Visual Studio will handle that automatically.